# Can't set envs for postgres image using docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

i set environment from .env file.

When i login in the container and try exec `psql -U admin -d art`.
It returns:

```
psql: error: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL:  database "art" does not exist
```

Although `echo $POSTGRES_DB` prints `art`

```
 db:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.db
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DB} // art
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER} // admin
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
```

My Dockerfile just copy sql scripts

```
FROM postgres:14.1-alpine3.15

WORKDIR /sql

COPY ./migrations/* ./
```

Comment: Have you *looked* at the value of those environment variables inside the container? Do they match the expected values?

Comment: Does the problem persist if you clean out the local database directory (`rm -rf data/db; mkdir data/db`)? Database initialization only happens when creating a new database, so if you previously started postgres with that directory with different credentials they won't get updated.